# Restart tomcat using gitlab-runner

Tags: permissions, tomcat, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have .gitlab-ci.yml configuration with:

```
deploy-integration:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cp target/example.war /var/webapps
    - service tomcat7 restart
```

But execution wasn't successful because of:

> $ service tomcat7 restart
>   You need root privileges to run this script
>   ERROR: Build failed: exit
>   status 1

What's the best way to restart tomcat with gitlab-runner? I want give permission to gitlab-runner just for this one command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `gitlab-runner` user to sudoers file:

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

to execute the specific command without asking for a password:

```
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service tomcat7 restart
```

Comment: Also changed from "- service tomcat7 restart" to "- sudo service tomcat7 restart" in .gitlab-ci.yml